# selection on multiple conditions doesn't work correctly in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which I create by loading a csv file and appending another df to (I know that appending is not done in place, so I assign the result of this operation to `df`). The dataframe has columns: stimulus (contains strings), syllable (contains numbers 1 or 2), response (contains strings).
If I do

```
df[df['syllable']==1]
```

or

```
edf[df['syllable']==2]
```

It selects the rows correctly.
But if I do:

```
df[(df['stimulus'].str.contains("bearded_guy"))&(df['syllable']==1)]
```

it selects rows where `syllable` is equal to 2 instead of 1.
[image]

Comment: can you put an example of your output after rerunning it , cs I've tried your example and it works correctly

Comment: I've added a picture with the output of running this code with syllable == 1 and syllable == 2. The code should select different rows, but if you see the output for bother cases it selects the same rows

Comment: Can you show us the two outputs with the syllable columns ?

Comment: In the output it seems that the columns are selected correctly, but check the row numbers: they are exactly the same which can be true. E.g. in row 60 syllable equals to 2, but the same row 60 is selected as having syllable 1 (which is not the case)

Comment: is it possible that while adding those two dataframes together you have for example the row with index `60` with `syllable=1` and at the same time a row also with index `60` but `syllable=2` ? the first number is just the index, not necessarily the row, you can have the same index more often

Comment: Thanks! turns out that was the case. I did df.reset_index() and it fixed everything

Comment: your welcome. glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.loc[(df['stimulus'].str.contains("bearded_guy"))&(df['syllable']==1), :]
```

Comment: It outputs an empty dataframe for syllable 2

Comment: you mean if you change the condition to `df['syllable']==1`  to `df['syllable']==2` in my code than you get an empty df ?

Comment: Sorry was my mistake, changing `df['syllable']==1` to `df['syllable']==2` outputs exactly the same rows. Like it does with my code

Comment: @AnastasiaLado FYI nevertheless it was a different issue. if you want to search/select rows in a df, you should use `loc/iloc`.